# Difference between javax.mail and javax.mail-api

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-mail

What is the difference between `javax.mail` and `javax.mail-api`?

I found those from maven repository.

When should each be used?

The software package comes with `javax.mail-api` but I could not get it work, so I downloaded `javax.mail`.

Answer (score 10):

`javax.mail-api` contains only interfaces, and `javax.mail` contains implementation.

Comment: Do i need both in my application ?

Comment: Yes, you need both. It is easy to do if our application is managed by maven for example.

Comment: I just used the mail API. But there is similar api with a different groupid that didnt resolve the issue so i used the below dependency and its able to resolve the dependency now. 
    <dependency>
     <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
     <version>1.6.0</version>
     <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
 </dependency>`

Comment: com.sun.mail:javax.mail includes the classes in javax.mail:javax.mail-api, so you need only the former.
For a case where the split can be useful, please see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.19.0. Here, javax:javax.mail-api is declared "provided", and com.sun.mail:javax.mail "runtime (optional)". This means that log4j is compiled against javax.mail-api, but anyone needing mail functionality in the logging setup (i.e. the SmptAppender) will need to include com.sun.mail:javax.mail in the classpath.

Comment: By the way, the word "javax" has been replaced by "jakarta" in recent versions, so they are now com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail and jakarta.mail:jakarta.mail-api, respectively. This is because "javax" can only be used in official Java code now.

Answer (score 4):

When libraries such as the [Java Mail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) are not published by their authors to Maven Central or other public repository, it's possible that different parties upload them, publishing it with conflicting `groupId`. It's probably the case for those two you're seeing.

This [artifact](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail) appears to contain the latest version of all you need to work with the mail api.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK from experience and looking at [maven central](http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=mail%20jar)...

When *javax.mail:**mail*** is bundled in a 'war' and is also in tomcat 'lib' one gets this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.mail.Session cannot be cast to javax.mail.Session
```

Similarly, *javax.mail:**javax-mail-api*** contains a *Session* class and is more than just interfaces.  When it is missing one gets this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Authenticator
```

*com.sun.mail:**javax-mail*** is something sun/oracle specific.